# loop attribute cannot be acessed in non-async contexts with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try to run this code
`

```
import json
import os
import random
from pprint import pprint

import aiohttp
import discord
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from mojang import api

# Functions

# Sends a Get request to a given url
def get_info(call):
    r = requests.get(call)
    return r.json()

# Get the sum of coins in the bazaar
def get_bazaar_buy_order_value(bazaar_data):
    sum_coins = 0
    price_increase_threshold = 2
    buy_order_values = []

    # For every product
    for item_name, item_data in bazaar_data.get("products", {}).items():

        item_sum_coins = 0

        # For every buy order
        for idx, buy_order in enumerate(item_data.get("buy_summary", [])):

            # If its the best price
            if(idx == 0):
                item_expected_value = buy_order.get("pricePerUnit", 0)
                item_sum_coins += buy_order.get("amount", 0) * buy_order.get("pricePerUnit", 0)
            # If its not the best price, check for reasonable price
            else:
                if(buy_order.get("pricePerUnit", 0) < (item_expected_value * price_increase_threshold)):
                    item_sum_coins += buy_order.get("amount", 0) * buy_order.get("pricePerUnit", 0)

        buy_order_values.append((item_name, item_sum_coins))
        sum_coins += item_sum_coins

    sort_bazaar_buy_orders_by_value(buy_order_values)
    return sum_coins

# Sorts and displays a list of buy order items by total value
def sort_bazaar_buy_orders_by_value(buy_order_values):

    # Sort items by values
    buy_order_values.sort(key = lambda x: -x[1])

    # Display items and values
    for (item_name, item_sum_coins) in buy_order_values:
        print(f"{item_name.ljust(30, ' ')} | {round(item_sum_coins):,}")

    return

# Returns Bazaar data
def get_bazaar_data():
    return get_info("https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar")

# Returns a specific item from the Bazaar
def get_bazaar_item():
    return

# Returns auction info from player uuid
def get_auctions_from_player(uuid):
    return get_info(f"https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auction?key={API_KEY}&player={uuid}")

# Returns current mayor/election data
def get_election_data():
    return get_info(f"https://api.hypixel.net/resources/skyblock/election")

# Returns a list of player profiles
def get_profiles_data():
    return get_info(f"https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/{example_uuid}")

# Returns player UUID when prompted with the name
async def get_uuid(name):
    return get_info(f"https://sky.shiiyu.moe/api/v2/profile/{name}")

# Discord Functions / Vars

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/',intents=intents)

# Hypixel Vars

Item = "Diamond"
API_FILE = open("API_KEY.json","r")
example_name = "4748"
example_uuid = "147ab344d3e54952b74a8b0fedee5534"
uuid_dashed = "147ab344-d3e5-4952-b74a-8b0fedee5534"
API_KEY = json.loads(API_FILE.read())["API_KEY"]
example_player_uuid = "147ab344d3e54952b74a8b0fedee5534"
auctions_player_url = f"https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/auction?key={API_KEY}&player={example_player_uuid}"

# Commands

@bot.command(name='bazaar', description = "Gives a detailed readout of a certain item in the bazaar", brief = "Get data of an item in bazaar")
async def bazaar(ctx):
    await ctx.send(get_bazaar_data())
    await ctx.send(API_KEY)

@bot.command(name="bazaartotal", description = "Show the total amount of coins on the bazaar at any given point", brief = "Shows the amount of coins in the bazaar")
async def baztot(ctx):
    await ctx.send(get_bazaar_buy_order_value(get_bazaar_data()))

@bot.command(name = "apikey", description = "Gives 4748's API key, make sure to remove me once publicly availible!", brief = "API Key")
async def key(ctx):
    await ctx.send(API_KEY)

@bot.command(name = "profiles", description = 'Get a list of player profiles and data about them', brief = "List player profiles")
async def prof(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Username to check?")
    message = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
    username = str(message.content)
    uuid = get_uuid(username)
    pprint(uuid)
    await ctx.send(uuid)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I get this error
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: loop attribute cannot be accessed in non-async contexts. Consider using either an asynchronous main function and passing it to asyncio.run or using asynchronous initialisation hooks such as Client.setup_hook` 
Anyone have a fix for this? The bot runs normally, but once I try to run /profiles it gives me that error. Also, other commands work fine, but when I try to access an api with a

Changed my code multiple times, putting the get_uuid command in async, and googling for a few hours. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Bot` variable is called `bot`, but you're using `client` in your `wait_for` statement.

You've got *both* a `discord.Client` ("client") and a `commands.Bot` ("bot") instance. This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If you only need Client features then use Client, if you want Bot features then use Bot. You can't use both at the same time.

Also, `wait_for` is a coroutine, so you should `await` it.

```py
# Yours:
message = client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)
#        ^^^^^^^
#        Missing await keyword & wrong bot variable

# Correct:
message = await bot.wait_for(...)
#         ^^^^^ ^^^
```

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for

PS `requests` is blocking and will make your whole bot freeze. Consider looking into an asynchronous http library like `aiohttp`.

Answer (score 0):

try to do this:
message = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.user == ctx.user)

I advise you to remove the 'name' from the slash command argument, it's better to just name the function and add an additional check for the channel 'm.channel == ctx.channel' to wait_for and split the file into several

Comment: Use \` code \`for proper code formating, just a lill hint :)